# Finding All DHCP and DNS servers

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I got a client who asked me to find all of his Dhcp and DNS servers with some additional info like DC servers and operationsystem
so i decided to try sharpen my powershell skills but im still new to this so i wrote this script but i guess something is still missing because it doesnt work

EDIT: i managed to find a way to get the info i want which is the   OS but it gets me back ALL the servers in the company

```
$servers = get-dhcpserverindc
   foreach($server in $Servers){
get-adcomputer -filter {Operatinsytem -like "*windows server*"} -properties 
Operatingsystem | sort name | format-table name,Operatinsytem

}
```

Comment: [`Get-DhcpServerInDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/get-dhcpserverindc?view=win10-ps) will already return all the DHCP servers in the domain run on it's own. The easiest way to list DNS servers in the domain is you use `nslookup`, set the type to `NS` and then search the domain name.

Comment: i know but what i wanted to do is to get full info like operating system and which one is the DC

Comment: Get-ADDomainController will retrieve the DCs - you can cross reference from there.

Comment: Did your client explicitly ask for Windows DNS/DHCP servers? Because they may have also have BIND or ISC DHCP running on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This is not too tricky.  First off, you connect to a machine with the RSAT Tools installed, like an admin server, jump box, or Domain Controller, and get a list of all DHCP Servers.

```
$DHCPServers = Get-DhcpServerInDC
```

Then we use PowerShell's built in looping logic to step through each server, and check for the OS info you need.

```
ForEach ($DHCPServer in $DHCPServers){
   $OSInfo = Get-CIMInstance -ComputerName $DHCPServer.DnsName -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem
}
```

Finally, we'll modify this above to return the info you're looking for, namely the IP Address, Name, and OS Version

```
ForEach ($DHCPServer in $DHCPServers){
   $OSInfo = Get-CIMInstance -ComputerName $DHCPServer.DnsName -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem
   [pscustomobject]@{
      ServerName = $DHCPServer.DnsName;
      IPAddress=$DHCPServer.IpAddress;
      OS=$OSInfo.Caption
    }
}

ServerName IPAddress    OS                                    
---------- ---------    --                                    
dc2016     192.168.10.1 Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
```

From there, you can store it in a variable, make it a spreadsheet, do whatever you need to do.

Hope this helps.

If this isn't working, make sure *you have enabled PowerShell Remoting first.*

Comment: Looks great,i will try this tomorrow and will definitely update you. im new to this community and so far you guys are great!

Comment: I see no update.  Hope something horrible did not happen.